# Get current user's comments using Youtube v3 api

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get youtube video comments for the current user. I need to get the user I am currently logged in. 
Checked out the doc
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list

For example, I can use the following code (Java client lib)

```
YouTube.Activities.List activityRequest = client.activities().list("id,snippet");
activityRequest.setMine(true);
```

For activities list, however, no such property is present for comments and comment threads. Is there an alternative approach to get currently logged in user's comments?